# Firewall rules between windows cluster

Tags: windows, firewall, cluster

I have been given the task to define firewall rules between 2 Windows clusters. The first cluster hosts a clustered middleware application and the second cluster hosts SQL Server. The 2 clusters are in different part of the network and separated by a physical firewall. Windows Firewall is off.

I am a little confused as to which IP I must include in the firewall rules between the 2 clusters. Indeed, each cluster has:

- 1 Virtual IP (By that I mean the IP given to the the clustered resource)
- 2 Physical IPs (By that I mean the IP given to the physical nodes of the cluster, each cluster having 2 physical machines in an Active/Passive configuration).

So for example, let's say I need to open the RPC port (TCP PORT 135), do I need to create 1 rule for every IP combination (3*3=9 rules in total)? Or do all traffic goes through the Virtual IP so that I would have only 1 rule to define?

Any help or even links to some online resource on how network traffic works between Windows Cluster would be appreciated.